# How can I remove a space between a textbox and a comma using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am dealing with an issue that seems very simple but can't resolve it in any way I can. I have a textbox followed by a comma.

```css
.nospace {
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  word-spacing: 0;
}
```

```html
<span class="nospace">
          <asp:TextBox ID="userInfo1" runat="server" CssClass="extension_textbox2 nospace"/>
           <span style="margin: 0;padding: 0;margin-left:0;word-spacing:0">,</span>
</span>
```

I don't want any space between the textbox and a comma but for some reason the space doesn't go away despite setting the margins and paddings to 0. I did try font-size=0 but that setting removes ability to enter any text into a textbox. Also, I saw some suggestions to use float left, but that setting moves comma or textbox to a beginning of a paragraph. How can I safely remove the space between the comma and a textbox?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Does it help to remove the whitespace between the `<span>` element and your text box?

Comment: If you use `.nospace * { float: left; }` it will not show the space. The space is caused by the whitespace (i.e., it's on a separate line) between the textbox and the inner span.

Comment: Another way would be to use `.nospace { display: inline-flex; }`, as also shown in the Q&A I proposed as a duplicate of this one.

Comment: Try adding this and give nospace class only in parent div
.nospace {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    word-spacing: 0;
    display: flex;
    gap: 0px;
    flex-direction: row;
}

Comment: display: inline-flex; worked!!!! Thank you very much!